How load AudioClip from Adressables in WebGL in Unity?
I wanted to optimize my application, added sounds to Addressables, but completely forgot that WaveGL has its own way of working with uploaded files, especially sounds.
I tried several options, and also conducted research on this topic, but I could not find a clear answer or one that met my requirements.
What I did:

tried to change the sound format mp3, waf, oog
tried to create an AudioClip, but either received errors about problems converting types, or the same error as before:

Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for clip "test_adressablesSound" (FMOD error: Unsupported file or audio format. )
UnityEngine.AudioSource:Play ()

My code to get AudioClip:
    [System.Serializable]
    public class SceneMusicGroupAdressables
    {
        public SceneNameInfo sceneNameInfo = default;
        public List<AssetReference> accetNameMusic = new List<AssetReference>();
    }

        public virtual async UniTask<AudioClip> GetClipFromNameAdressbless(string clipName)
        {
            foreach (var sceneMusicGroups in sceneMusicGroupsAdressables)
            {
                foreach (var asset in sceneMusicGroups.accetNameMusic)
                {
                    if (asset.AssetGUID == clipName)
                    {
                        if (lastAsset.IsValid())
                        {
                            lastAsset.ReleaseAsset();
                        }
                        loadAsset = asset.LoadAssetAsync<AudioClip>();
                        await loadAsset;

                        if (loadAsset.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
                        {
                            lastAsset = asset;
                            audio = (AudioClip)loadAsset.Result;
                            return audio;   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return audio;
        }

Success Get AudioClip
I know about the way to download AudioClip via www.GetAudioClip(false, false), but I don't know how to get the path for the addressables files in the webGL build in the Local/Default Group.
I'm only interested in this group, I don't intend to have resources on remote servers.
Can you help me or suggest anything that would help me solve this problem?
